# cudaErrorInvalidValue returned by cudaMemcpy

Tags: cuda

I have a problem in my code, more precisely both cudaMemcpy calls return cudaErrorInvalidValue  in the following code:.

```
const int N = 3 ;
double d_doc[N][4][2500];
double d_vec_res[N][2];
double d_req[4][100];.
.
.
.    
void similarity (double doc[][4][2500], double req[4][100], double vec_res[][2]) 
    {         
        int r =  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_req , 4*100*sizeof(double) ); // r = cudaSuccess
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_doc , N*2500*4*sizeof(double) );
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_vec_res , N*2*sizeof(double) );         
        int err =  cudaMemcpy(d_req, req, 4*100*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // err = cudaErrorInvalidValue
        int err2 = cudaMemcpy(d_doc, doc, N*4*2500*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // err = cudaErrorInvalidValue               
        sim<<<1, N>>>(d_doc,d_req,d_vec_res);        
        cudaMemcpy(vec_res, d_vec_res, 2*N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
         cudaFree(d_req);
         cudaFree(d_doc);
         cudaFree(d_vec_res);
     }
```

Could you help me please?.

Comment: there are two cudaMemcpy calls in that code. Should we guess which one is reporting the error?

Comment: Both of them ! thank you for your comment

Comment: Please extend you code to a [mcve], in your case the focus should be on _complete_. It would be helpful if you would use [error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14038590/5085250) on the relevant part of your question, i.e. the `memcpy`. This makes it easy to verify the behaviour.

Comment: @havogt thank you for your suggestions

Comment: @Fate7: Your edit to the code neither provides compileable code, nor makes any sense. If `d_doc` is a statically defined array, why are you passing it to cudaMalloc?

Comment: Your code is clearly broken.  As @talonmies has pointed out, the pointers for `d_doc`, `d_vec_res` and `d_req` are not correctly defined.  Have you looked at any basic sample codes to see how this is done?  Take a look at the vectorAdd sample code.   And a solution probably can't be given or discussed, without knowing how you intend to use those data structures (arrays) in device code.  The solution might be as simple as defining `double *d_doc, *d_vec_res, *d_req;` instead.  But if you are attempting multiple-subscripted access in your `sim` kernel, that won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the arrays as pointers

```
double *d_doc, *d_vec_res, *d_req;
```

and in your kernel, access those arrays as linear array, not as multidimensional arrays.